Eisenstein inversion problem and uniqueness of the periods
I am currently reading Apostol's Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory. Theorem 2.9 states that we can "invert" the Weierstrassian elliptic invariants: given two complex numbers $a_2,a_3$ such that $a_2^3-27a_3^2\neq0$, there exists $\omega_1,\omega_2\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\omega_2/\omega_1\notin \mathbb{R}$ and $g_2(\omega_1,\omega_2)=a_2$ and  $g_3(\omega_1,\omega_2)=a_3$. This is proven by explicit construction of the periods $\omega_1,\omega_2$ utilizing the Klein J invariants properties. Namely, $J(\tau)$ takes every value once in the closure of fundamental region. My question is  what can be said about uniqueness of $\omega_1,\omega_2$, since we know that the $\tau\in R_\Gamma^c$ we use in the construction is unique? Obviously if we take two equivalent systems of periods they generate the samme lattice hence same invariants. Are there any other $\omega_1',\omega_2'$ that satisfy this property without being equivalent to $\omega_1,\omega_2$? If the elliptic invariants were same then every Eisenstein series of the systems would be the same since every Eisenstein serie is a combination of the series of order 4 and 6. Is this enough to conclude the lattices are same hence the systems are equivalent?
